# Have a select link in View. When clicked, Display more info about selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to add functionality to allow a user to select an Asset, and upon their select, display the rest of the information about the selected Asset.

Here is my Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AssetManagementSystem.Models.Asset>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetMake.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssetType.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CPU.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department.DepartmentName)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssetMake.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssetType.Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CPU.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.DepartmentName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id = item.AssetID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AssetID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AssetID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AssetID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Basically, i want to display the rest of the information about the Asset when the user clicks "Select".

Here is my AssetModel:

```
 public class Asset
 {
    [Key]
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public int AssetMakeID { get; set; }
    public int AssetTypeID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string AssetModel { get; set; }
    public string AssetSerialNo { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string WarrantyInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePurchased { get; set; }
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public int CPUID { get; set; }
    public string RAM { get; set; }
    public string HardDrive { get; set; }
    public int OperatingSystemID { get; set; }
    public string OperatingSystemProductKey { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetType AssetType { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual CPU CPU { get; set; }
    public virtual OperatingSyst OperatingSyst { get; set; }
    public virtual AssetMake AssetMake { get; set; }
```

Here is the index method in my Asset Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var asset = db.Asset
        .Include(a => a.AssetMake)
        .Include(a => a.AssetType)
        .Include(a => a.CPU)
        .Include(a => a.Department)
        .Include(a => a.OperatingSyst);
    return View(asset.ToList());
}
```

How do i go about adding this functionality to allow a user to select an asset and then the asset info be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You already have it.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AssetID })
```

Then on your details page put the Html helpers for the additional information you would like to display. I am using MVC 6 but the same thing can be applied to whatever version you are using. The target="_blank" will just open in another tab so they can easily go back.

```
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.AssetId">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.AssetId" target="_blank">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.AssetId">Delete</a>
```